# Android Implement ViewModel Runtime Error

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

So I'm trying to understand the ViewModel paradigm by using the code from the Android Developer documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#kotlin)

I can't seem to find an example of how to set the value of the users variable. **users.value** and **users.postValue** don't seem to work, I get a runtime error.

**UPDATE:**

I simplified the example in the Android Developer Documentation by using a primitive:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val user: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>().also {
            loadUser()
        }
    }

    fun getUser(): LiveData<String> {
        return user
    }

    private fun loadUser() {
        user.postValue("My String")
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Mark Keen is right. However he inspired me to come up with a different solution than his suggestion in the comments. I needed to understand his motivation for setting the value of the string in the constructor of **MutableLiveData** instead of using **user.value** or **user.postValue()**. The motivation is that I was trying to set the value of **user** before the variable got initialized. So I thought in this case why not use a lambda expression to pass the value from the scope function directly to loadUsers()?

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val users: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>().also {
            mutableLiveDataString ->
            loadUsers(mutableLiveDataString)
        }
    }

    fun getUsers(): LiveData<String> {
        return users //My Really Cool String
    }

    private fun loadUsers(users: MutableLiveData<String>) {
        users.postValue("My Really Cool String")
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for others if you can post your code.

Comment: You are trying to call itself, `user`, in `loadUser()` before the `Lazy` variable is initialized. Just do `MutableLiveData<String>("My String")`.  The Android example is slightly opaque as it comments "do some asynchronous load", but you are doing this "synchronously" and that makes the difference here.